# Get parent node based on current node and edge value in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, parent-child, path-finding

I am making a uniform cost search algorithm (for fun, not an assignment or anything) and I have an array that keeps tracks of the nodes and edge values that it passes. However I am trying to get it to add the edge values together based on the path it took.

How does one get the parent node based on the current node and edge value?

Trail of nodes it has visited (for example) [Started from A, visited C, and now on B (from A)]:

```
Starting point:  B
Graph of current node:  {'A': 3, 'D': 8}
Trail  {'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'B': 3}
Nodes_to_expand {'C': 2, 'B': 3, 'E': 5, 'D': 6}
```

Graph (Python dictionary):

```
graph = {'A': {'B':3, 'C':2, 'D': 6},
     'B': {'A':3, 'D':8},
     'C': {'D':7, 'E':5},
     'D': {'E':-2},
     'E':{}}
```

Comment: Why not make the trail a list (ordered) of visited nodes instead of a dictionary, then you can lookup the parent as `trail[step-1]`.

Comment: I also need to keep track of the edge values as well, so that's why I need both the node and the value of the edges stored.

Comment: Even if that's the case, you can use a list of tuples `[(node, edge), ...]` or something similar. My point is keep track of the visit order as well.